# Why did Mrs Gump feel that Elvis Presley's Hound Dog was inappropriate for children?

Tags: plot-explanation, forrest-gump

Young Forrest Gump and Mrs Gump were out shopping, and walked right by Benson's furniture
and appliance store. They came across a TV set playing Elvis Presley "[Hound Dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzQ8GDBA8Is)" song:

[image]

> Mrs Gump: This is **not for children's eyes**.

Why did Mrs Gump feel that Elvis Presley's Hound Dog was inappropriate for children?

Comment: Watching Forrest Gump, you need a decent grasp of American cultural changes & history in the latter part of the 20th century, otherwise you just won't understand any of the references. This covers some aspects of it, though not all - https://screenrant.com/forrest-gump-movie-true-story-history-events-accuracy/ This covers some more - https://www.looper.com/1176100/the-best-historical-references-in-forrest-gump/

Comment: She was just echoing what many parents felt at the time. His early TV appearances only showed him from above the waist, so viewers couldn't see his hips swaying provocatively.

Comment: [This short clip answers the question](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/yB8GXtFAiEE), but I don't think I'd get away with posting this as an answer.

Comment: I don't know that she thought about "Hound Dog" in particular.  If she recognized "Hound Dog" as an Elivs Presley song and thought Presley was in general inappropriate for children, why would she waste time on a particular song?

Comment: Wasn't that song the one the nickname "Elvis the pelvis" came from?

Comment: It's amazing how young some people are!  This was a completely normal viewpoint at the time.  "Rock and roll" was so hated that it was common that people organized BURNING his records, same with the Beatles a little later.  You can easily google this part of history if you're (lucky for you) way young!  https://faroutmagazine.co.uk/elvis-presley-burning-effigies/

Comment: @WoJ it looks like that specifically is a bit of an urban myth; that particular nickname was used generally in newspapers and such for at least a year previous, it seems, during his growth in fame ... as with anything these days easy to google discussion on it https://faroutmagazine.co.uk/elvis-presley-burning-effigies/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Some people thought it was too 'sexually explicit' at the time.

From [Graceland](https://www.graceland.com/elvis-news/posts/today-in-elvis-history-famous-hound-dog-performance-in-1956)…

> Today marks the day Elvis famously performed "Hound Dog" on "The
> Milton Berle Show" and stirred up quite a frenzy. On June 5, 1956,
> Elvis set his guitar to the side and performed what came to be known
> as one of the most controversial performances in television history.
> The provocative hip-swinging dance moves caused a national scandal and
> set the stage for the King of Rock 'n' Roll's place in history.
>
> His performance of "Hound Dog" drove the kids in the audience wild and
> disgusted the press and some of the adult viewers. His sexy moves and
> black-influenced sound was condemned by certain factions of the
> “morally concerned” establishment and the religious community, but his
> seemingly unstoppable popularity continued to grow to new heights.